# Find first valid value in each gorup

Tags: python, pandas

This is a bit of a peculiar task, but I'm trying to come up with an efficient way of finding the first numerical values among several columns for each group. So for the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a':[1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2],
    'b':[2,np.nan,4,np.nan,5,np.nan,1,np.nan],
    'c':[np.nan,1,4,0,4,np.nan,6,np.nan],
    'd':[np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 1,6,2,5,np.nan]
})
```

```
   a    b    c    d
0  1  2.0  NaN  NaN
1  1  NaN  1.0  NaN
2  1  4.0  4.0  NaN
3  1  NaN  0.0  1.0
4  1  5.0  4.0  6.0
5  2  NaN  NaN  2.0
6  2  1.0  6.0  5.0
7  2  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

For each `a`, I'd like a single row containing the first valid value in each of the columns, so:

```
   a   b    c    d
0  1  2.0  1.0  1.0
2  2  1.0  6.0  2.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you may check with `first` (Return the first not null value)

```
df.groupby('a').first()
Out[369]: 
     b    c    d
a               
1  2.0  1.0  1.0
2  1.0  6.0  2.0
```

If the index is matter `bfill` + `drop_duplicates`

```
df.groupby('a').bfill().drop_duplicates('a')
Out[374]: 
   a    b    c    d
0  1  2.0  1.0  1.0
5  2  1.0  6.0  2.0
```

Comment: @yatu ah yw :-)

Comment: bfill works too of course, duh this is simpler than I was thinking, guess I just didnt give it enough time